# Javascript not reading value from a radio button & hidden box

Tags: javascript, html

when i select the radio button my other function enables the textbox & i want to read the value from it

```js
function calculate() {
  var currency = parseFloat(0);
  var message = "";


  currency = document.getElementsByName("val")[0].value;

  message = ("You Have Entered Amount : " + currency);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <input type="radio" name="inputControl" value="1" onchange="setvisible(this.value)"> Euro
</td>

<td><input type="number" name="val" size="10" id="set1" style="visibility:hidden;">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove [0].value part.  Try this

> currency=document.getElementsByName("val")

Comment: i did that and it gives this :  You Have Entered Amount : [object NodeList]

Comment: This could be unrelated error. Look at console log for value of $currency variable

Comment: Also, perhaps post the remaining HTML to troubleshoot

Comment: if this answers the original question, choose answer by clicking it